# Optimizing Python Code for Competitions

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to get familiar with it by solving problems on CodeChef. I'm attempting to solve the Easy problem [Number Game](https://www.codechef.com/problems/NUMBGAME). The issue is that the execution time is too long for my code.

I have translated the Python solution I wrote into C++, and the submission was accepted, so I know I have a correct answer, and it's just off by a constant multiple.

**Is it possible to solve this problem in Python 3 in the allotted time? Can you help me speed up my code to accomplish this?**

```
import time

def getStartValues(A, M):
    startVals = [0]*M
    b = [0]*len(A)
    for i in range(len(A)-1):
        b[i+1] = (10*b[i] + A[i]) % M
    f = 0
    power = 1
    for i in range(len(A)-1,0,-1):
        startVals[(b[i]*power + f) % M] += 1
        f = (A[i]*power + f) % M
        power = (power*10 % M)
    startVals[f] += 1
    return startVals, power

def checkValues(i, startVals, M, powNm1, checked, chklst):
    if checked[i] == 1:
        return startVals[i]
    q = [i]
    chk = [0]*M
    chk[i] = 1
    while len(q) > 0:
        val = q.pop(0)
        for j in chklst:
            val2 = (powNm1*val + j) % M
            if checked[val2] > 0:
                checked[i] = 1
                return startVals[i]
            elif chk[val2] == 0:
                q.append(val2)
                chk[val2] = 1
    return 0

def compute(A, M):
    startVals, power = getStartValues(A, M)

    checked = [0]*M
    checked[0] = 1
    chklst = [j for j in range(M) if startVals[j] > 0]
    total = 0
    for i in chklst:
        c = checkValues(i, startVals, M, power, checked, chklst)
        total += c

    return total

start = time.time()
file = open('numbgame.in', 'r')
#T = int(input())
T = int(file.readline())
for i in range(T):
    #A, M = input().split()
    A, M = file.readline().split()
    A = list(map(int,A))
    M = int(M)
    print(compute(A, M))
tDiff = time.time() - start
print('Total time: %s' % tDiff)
```

Note that I have modified the code to read from a file and to display execution time, as a convenience, and some small alterations are needed before it can be submitted.

getStartValues takes in the (big) list of digits of the input A and the (small) integer M and returns the values modulo M that can be generated from A by removing a single digit.

checkValues takes an index i, the list startValues, the integer M, the integer powNm1 (which is the value 10^(n-1) mod M, where n is the number of digits in A, a list checked that keeps track of whether a value has already been determined to be solvable, and the list chklst (which contains the indices i such that startValues[i] > 0).

The majority of the time is spent in the function getStartValues, since A could be up to 10^6 digits long. On my desktop, the getStartValues function call takes about 1.2s, while the rest of the compute function takes about 0.04s (for worst case inputs).

Comment: probably it's your while loop.. q.qsize is not going up or down

Comment: Most of these competitions are designed so that ti'll easily pass if you use the right algorithm, but usually won't if you use the wrong algorithm. If your code just barely passes, you shouldn't count that as success, because they could just slightly change the test values and next time it'll fail—or it may even fail on the same tests just because the system is more loaded (more people running tests at the same time as you). And likewise, if it just barely fails, you shouldn't try to optimize out 10% of the time. But of course all that "most" and "usually" matters; maybe this is an exception.

Comment: Also, you've tagged this `python-3.x`, but your code uses `psyco`. I'm pretty sure the Python 3.x branch of `psyco` was abandoned unfinished. If you're relying on JIT to speed your code up, just run under PyPy instead of CPython.

Comment: q is a queue. q.get() reduces the size of q.qsize(). As I said, I wrote the same code in C++, and it was accepted. Also, the psyco thing is just something I threw on there just in case; it doesn't actually use it because the import fails.

Comment: But I'll give decent odds that if you run this under PyPy, it does pass. And, if you don't want to rethink your algorithm and just want to get a constant-factor speedup, that's almost always the easiest first thing to try.

Comment: Also, `queue.Queue()` isn't a simple queue, it's an auto-synchronizing queue for use in multithreading. You're effectively doing an extra lock acquire and release around every `get` and `put`, which is a slow thing to do when you don't need it. Just use a `list` or a `collections.deque`. (And this should be obvious from the very start of the `queue` module docs or interactive `help`, so… why are you using it?)

Comment: I switched the queue to a list, and it had a very noticeable impact on the run time. Thanks! I was using it because I'm bad :'( It still exceeds the time limit, though.

Comment: OK, well, since it takes so long just to iterate through a long list and perform some basic arithmetic, I'm going to assume there's just no way to speed that up enough in Python, and that submitting a sufficiently fast solution in an interpreted language like that just isn't possible with the constraints.